# HTTP -> HTTPS Redirection with OpenBSD's httpd

Tags: httpd, openbsd

Running OpenBSD 4.4-stable with the built-in httpd daemon and PHP5 which has been moved from an Ubuntu 8.04-server box. Since the movement phpMyAdmin seems to generate the following error every so often (and sometimes all the time, like logging in):

```
Bad Request
Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Reason: You're speaking plain HTTP to an SSL-enabled server port.
Instead use the HTTPS scheme to access this URL, please.
```

The address for phpMyAdmin is under an https:// URL, and when this error occurs phpMyAdmin is trying to use http://domain.com:443/ which obviously won't work.

I also have a mod_rewrite rule to always force HTTPS but since the browser is forcing the 443 port it never gets fired.

Any ideas how to remedy this?

#### [EDIT]

Here is my vhost directives since those were requested:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/htdocs
    RewriteEngine   On
    RewriteCond     %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule     (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/htdocs
    ErrorLog        logs/error_log
    TransferLog     logs/access_log
    RewriteCond     %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^(TRACE|TRACK)
    RewriteRule     .* - [F]
</VirtualHost>
```

#### [EDIT 2]

I turned off the rewrite rule and everything works like a charm :/ Not sure what to make of that since the same rewrite rule works elsewhere.

Comment: Can you dump the relevant portions of your Apache config here? This sounds like a bad rewrite rule...

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 2):

In my setup of PHPMyAdmin I have an apache config that looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 72.233.89.20:80>
    ServerName mysql
    ServerAlias mysql.*
    UseCanonicalName Off
    DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin/html/
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/phpmyadmin/
    php_admin_value file_uploads 1
    php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/phpmyadmin/phptmp/
    php_admin_value session.save_path /var/www/phpmyadmin/phptmp/
</VirtualHost>
#
######
# Interface for https (openssl)
######
#
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost 72.233.89.20:443>
        ServerName mysql
        ServerAlias mysql.*
        UseCanonicalName Off
        DocumentRoot /var/www/phpmyadmin/ssl
        SSLEngine on
        SSLCertificateFile    /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/server.crt
        SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/httpd/conf/ssl/server.key
        DirectoryIndex index.html index.htm index.php
        AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

        php_admin_value open_basedir /var/www/phpmyadmin/
        php_admin_value file_uploads 1
        php_admin_value upload_tmp_dir /var/www/phpmyadmin/phptmp/
        php_admin_value session.save_path /var/www/phpmyadmin/phptmp/
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

Note how it is set up on port 80 and port 443.

In the webroot of http (port 80) I just have a .htaccess file that looks like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

To redirect it all to SSL.

All of the PHPMyAdmin files live in the SSL directory.

I suggest setting up your vhost to serve on both port 80 and port 443.  PHPMyAdmin itself is just a php script, it does not force any port.  It is all about how your webserver/vhosts are configured.

Comment: You don't need the Rewrite directives in the .htaccess file - you can just drop them into the <VirtualHost ip:80> section.

Answer (score 0):

Since browsers generally don't redirect from port 80 to port 443, it may be the first page returned from phpmyadmin that's causing the change. Take a look at your phpmyadmin configuration to see what differences occur with:

- config.inc.php

  > $cfg['ForceSSL'] boolean

*Whether to force using https while accessing phpMyAdmin.*

According to the [documentation](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/), it is on by default, but since you have mod_rewrite working, there might be a 'disconnect?'

And it seems that these days everyone's pointing at putting in a provision for Microsoft IE such as:

- [SSL and MSIE clients](http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/#faq1_10)

> SetEnvIf User-Agent ".*MSIE.*" nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown

### Otherwise, ...

By any chance would using the OpenBSD Apache 2.0.x packages make a difference for you ?

It seems that your Ubuntu configuration will have used Apache 2.0 and you've moved your system (and configurations) onto a default OpenBSD configuration using Apache 1.3.x

I think you'll need to at least look at the php_admin_value's shown by WerkkreW.

WHEN the simple things don't work, we can always bump up the *LogLevel* data and look at the results from there. It's noisy, but always an option.

Enable SSLOptions StdEnvVars in [Apache Configuration](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/mod/mod_ssl.html#ssloptions)

> StdEnvVars
>   When this option is enabled, the standard set of SSL related CGI/SSI environment variables are created. This per default is disabled for performance reasons, because the information extraction step is a rather expensive operation. So one usually enables this option for CGI and SSI requests only.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the suggestions. I've tried the above suggestions and still no go (except for the IE thing, this happens in both Firefox and IE). As part of a new company policy we're switching everything over to CentOS instead of the mix of OSes we have now, so I'll see if its still doing it after that. Thanks!

Comment: No probs and good luck.